# Синтаксический разбор сложного предложения (2)

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, сложное-предложение

Помогите сделать синтаксический разбор сложного предложения по частям.

*Информационная ценность есть качество самих элементов языка, но, естественно, она находится в тесной зависимости от количества и качества информации, изложенной на  данном языке в оригинальных и переводных публикациях* (В. Г. Костомаров).

Comment: Вы б, прежде чем синтаксическим разбором заниматься, грамотно писать научились. А то ощущение было, что вопрос задал китаец, весьма отдаленно знакомый с русским языком, или дремучий крестьянин из глухого села 19 века, ей Богу!  
"Сделать" пишется через С, "чАстям" — через А. Не говоря уж о том, что, когда что-то просите, нужно говорить "пожалуйста".

Answer (score 3):

Это сложносочиненное предложение, состоящее из двух простых предложений. Первое предложение - "Информационная ценность есть качество самих элементов языка". Второе предложение - вся остальная часть. Грамматическая основа первого предложения - "ценность есть качество". Грамматическая основа второго предложения - "она находится". Второе предложение осложнено вводным словом "естественно" и обособленным определением "изложенной на данном языке в оригинальных и переводных публикациях", выраженным причастным оборотом